# Let $n>3$ and $A=\{1, 2, \ldots , n\}$. How many subsets $B$ of $A$ contain both $1$ and $2$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I think I was able to find the answer from some guesswork, but I'm unsure of how to prove the result.

If $n=5$, then there are $2^5=32$ total subsets by the power set rule.

The subsets that contain $1$ and $2$ are $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $\{1,2,4\}$, $\{1,2,4,5\}$, $\{1,2,5\}$, $\{1,2,3,5\}$.

There are $8$ subsets listed here, and I know that $8=2^3$. I also noticed that $2^3=2^{5-2}$.

Therefore, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there would be $2^{n-2}$ subsets that contain $1$ and $2$.

For a set with $n$ elements, there would be $2^n$ subsets. To prove my formula rigorously, I know that I cannot just list out the subsets, so now I'm stuck.

Note: my question might be similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904805/how-many-subsets-of-1-2-n-contain-1-and-how-many-dont).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to ''add'' some subset of $\{3,4,5...,n\}$ to the set $\{1,2\}$. But the number of such subsets is exactly $2^{n-2}$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bijection $\varphi$ between subsets of $A$ containing $1$ and $2$ and subsets of $B=\{3,4,\ldots,n\}$: if $1,2\in X\subseteq A$, $\varphi(X)=X\setminus\{1,2\}$. $B$ has $n-2$ elements, so it has $2^{n-2}$ subsets, and $A$ therefore has $2^{n-2}$ subsets that contain $1$ and $2$.